# Burning Arduino bootloader with Atmel-ICE results in avrdude throwing a "verification error"

Tags: arduino, bootloader, atmega, atmel, avrdude

I'm trying to burn an Arduino bootloader on an `Arduino UNO` board with the `Atmel-ICE` probe. Unfortunately, `avrdude` throws an error message when verifying the bytes.

## 1. Hardware setup

My hardware setup looks like this:

[image]

By the way - I'm working on a 64-bit Windows 10 PC.

## 2. Atmel-ICE driver

At first I thought that the `Atmel-ICE` doesn't require installation, because Windows recognizes it as an HID-device. However, I quickly learned that `avrdude` - launched by the Arduino IDE - needs another driver to interact with the `Atmel-ICE`. Therefore, I installed the `libusb-win32` driver with Zadig (just as suggested on the GitHub thread https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/4368):

[image]

The driver installation succeeded, and I observe a change in the Windows Device Manager. The `Atmel-ICE` probe no longer appears as an HID-device but as a `libusb-win32` device instead:

[image]

I believe the `Atmel-ICE` is now ready to be used with `avrdude`.

## 3. Software setup

I'm running a fresh-installed Arduino IDE (version 1.8.13) on a Windows 10 PC. First I activate maximal verbosity for the console output (`File` > `Preferences` > `Show verbose output`). Next, I select the probe: `Tools` > `Programmer` > `Atmel-ICE (AVR)`

[image]

Next I select my board: `Tools` > `Board` > `Arduino AVR Boards` > `Arduino UNO`

[image]

Finally, I burn the bootloader: `Tools` > `Burn Bootloader`

[image]

In the console output, I can see two `avrdude` commands being launched.

#### 3.1 First avrdude command

The first `avrdude` command looks like this:

```sh
avrdude -CC:\Program Files (x86)\.../avrdude.conf
        -v
        -patmega328p
        -catmelice_isp
        -Pusb
        -e
        -Ulock:w:0x3F:m
        -Uefuse:w:0xFD:m
        -Uhfuse:w:0xDE:m
        -Ulfuse:w:0xFF:m
```

the output for this command is:

```sh
avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : usb
         Using Programmer              : atmelice_isp
avrdude: usbhid_open(): No device found
avrdude: usbdev_open(): Found Atmel-ICE CMSIS-DAP, serno: J42700007942
avrdude: Found CMSIS-DAP compliant device, using EDBG protocol
         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : JTAG3_ISP
         Description     : Atmel-ICE (ARM/AVR) in ISP mode
         Vtarget         : 5.0 V
         SCK period      : 125.00 us

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f (probably m328p)
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: reading input file "0x3F"
avrdude: writing lock (1 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: 1 bytes of lock written
avrdude: verifying lock memory against 0x3F:
avrdude: load data lock data from input file 0x3F:
avrdude: input file 0x3F contains 1 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip lock data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: WARNING: invalid value for unused bits in fuse "lock", should be set to 1 according to datasheet
This behaviour is deprecated and will result in an error in future version
You probably want to use 0xff instead of 0x3f (double check with your datasheet first).
avrdude: 1 bytes of lock verified
avrdude: reading input file "0xFD"
avrdude: writing efuse (1 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.09s

avrdude: 1 bytes of efuse written
avrdude: verifying efuse memory against 0xFD:
avrdude: load data efuse data from input file 0xFD:
avrdude: input file 0xFD contains 1 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip efuse data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1 bytes of efuse verified
avrdude: reading input file "0xDE"
avrdude: writing hfuse (1 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.09s

avrdude: 1 bytes of hfuse written
avrdude: verifying hfuse memory against 0xDE:
avrdude: load data hfuse data from input file 0xDE:
avrdude: input file 0xDE contains 1 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip hfuse data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1 bytes of hfuse verified
avrdude: reading input file "0xFF"
avrdude: writing lfuse (1 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.09s

avrdude: 1 bytes of lfuse written
avrdude: verifying lfuse memory against 0xFF:
avrdude: load data lfuse data from input file 0xFF:
avrdude: input file 0xFF contains 1 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip lfuse data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1 bytes of lfuse verified

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

That looks good.

#### 3.2 Second avrdude command

The second `avrdude` command is:

```sh
avrdude -CC:\Program Files (x86)\.../avrdude.conf
        -v
        -patmega328p
        -catmelice_isp
        -Pusb
        -Uflash:w:C:\Program Files (x86)\.../optiboot_atmega328.hex:i
        -Ulock:w:0x0F:m
```

with the following output:

```sh
avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : usb
         Using Programmer              : atmelice_isp
avrdude: usbhid_open(): No device found
avrdude: usbdev_open(): Found Atmel-ICE CMSIS-DAP, serno: J42700007942
avrdude: Found CMSIS-DAP compliant device, using EDBG protocol
         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : JTAG3_ISP
         Description     : Atmel-ICE (ARM/AVR) in ISP mode
         Vtarget         : 5.0 V
         SCK period      : 125.00 us

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f (probably m328p)
avrdude: NOTE: "flash" memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed
         To disable this feature, specify the -D option.
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: reading input file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr/bootloaders/optiboot/optiboot_atmega328.hex"
avrdude: writing flash (32768 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% -0.00s

avrdude: 32768 bytes of flash written
avrdude: verifying flash memory against C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr/bootloaders/optiboot/optiboot_atmega328.hex:
avrdude: load data flash data from input file C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr/bootloaders/optiboot/optiboot_atmega328.hex:
avrdude: input file C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr/bootloaders/optiboot/optiboot_atmega328.hex contains 32768 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% -0.00s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 32768 bytes of flash verified
avrdude: reading input file "0x0F"
avrdude: writing lock (1 bytes):

Error while burning bootloader.
Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: 1 bytes of lock written
avrdude: verifying lock memory against 0x0F:
avrdude: load data lock data from input file 0x0F:
avrdude: input file 0x0F contains 1 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip lock data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0000
         0xff != 0x0f
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

#### 3.3 The error message

As you can see, `avrdude` throws this error message:

```sh
avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0000
         0xff != 0x0f
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch
```

What should I do to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

I just tried something. I entered the exact same commands that the Arduino IDE prints in its console into a Windows terminal.

### 1. Same commands - but in Windows Terminal

I opened a Windows Terminal and entered the two `avrdude` commands just as I see them in the Arduino IDE console.

#### 1.1 First avrdude command

The first command I entered is this one:

```sh
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude" -C"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf" -v -patmega328p -catmelice_isp -Pusb -e -Ulock:w:0x3F:m -Uefuse:w:0xFD:m -Uhfuse:w:0xDE:m -Ulfuse:w:0xFF:m
```

Restyled and reformatted, it looks like this (see also my original post):

```sh
avrdude -C C:/Program Files (x86)/.../avrdude.conf
        -v
        -patmega328p
        -catmelice_isp
        -Pusb
        -e
        -Ulock:w:0x3F:m
        -Uefuse:w:0xFD:m
        -Uhfuse:w:0xDE:m
        -Ulfuse:w:0xFF:m
```

The output is exactly the same as before (see my original post), with a few exceptions. After printing the table with memory info, `avrdude` prints this line:

`avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions`

In the original output (from the Arduino IDE console), the following is printed right after that line:

```sh
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f (probably m328p)
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: reading input file "0x3F"
```

In the Windows terminal output, I see this instead:

```sh
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f (probably m328p)
avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as FF
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as DE
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as FD
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: reading input file "0x3F"
```

Another difference is all the way at the end of the output. The original output (from the Arduino IDE console, see original post) ends like this:

```sh
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1 bytes of lfuse verified

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

While the Windows terminal outputs this:

```sh
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1 bytes of lfuse verified

avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as FF
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as DE
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as FD
avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (E:FD, H:DE, L:FF)

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Here is the complete output:

```sh
avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : usb
         Using Programmer              : atmelice_isp
avrdude: usbhid_open(): No device found
avrdude: usbdev_open(): Found Atmel-ICE CMSIS-DAP, serno: J42700007942
avrdude: Found CMSIS-DAP compliant device, using EDBG protocol
         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : JTAG3_ISP
         Description     : Atmel-ICE (ARM/AVR) in ISP mode
         Vtarget         : 5.1 V
         SCK period      : 125.00 us

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f (probably m328p)
avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as FF
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as DE
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as FD
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: reading input file "0x3F"
avrdude: writing lock (1 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: 1 bytes of lock written
avrdude: verifying lock memory against 0x3F:
avrdude: load data lock data from input file 0x3F:
avrdude: input file 0x3F contains 1 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip lock data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: WARNING: invalid value for unused bits in fuse "lock", should be set to 1 according to datasheet
This behaviour is deprecated and will result in an error in future version
You probably want to use 0xff instead of 0x3f (double check with your datasheet first).
avrdude: 1 bytes of lock verified
avrdude: reading input file "0xFD"
avrdude: writing efuse (1 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.10s

avrdude: 1 bytes of efuse written
avrdude: verifying efuse memory against 0xFD:
avrdude: load data efuse data from input file 0xFD:
avrdude: input file 0xFD contains 1 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip efuse data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1 bytes of efuse verified
avrdude: reading input file "0xDE"
avrdude: writing hfuse (1 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.10s

avrdude: 1 bytes of hfuse written
avrdude: verifying hfuse memory against 0xDE:
avrdude: load data hfuse data from input file 0xDE:
avrdude: input file 0xDE contains 1 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip hfuse data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% -0.00s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1 bytes of hfuse verified
avrdude: reading input file "0xFF"
avrdude: writing lfuse (1 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.10s

avrdude: 1 bytes of lfuse written
avrdude: verifying lfuse memory against 0xFF:
avrdude: load data lfuse data from input file 0xFF:
avrdude: input file 0xFF contains 1 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip lfuse data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1 bytes of lfuse verified

avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as FF
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as DE
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as FD
avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (E:FD, H:DE, L:FF)

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

#### 1.2 Second avrdude command

The second `avrdude` command I enter is this one:

```sh
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude" -C"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf" -v -patmega328p -catmelice_isp -Pusb -Uflash:w:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr/bootloaders/optiboot/optiboot_atmega328.hex":i -Ulock:w:0x0F:m
```

Restyled and reformatted, it looks like this (see also my original post):

```sh
avrdude -C C:/Program Files (x86)/.../avrdude.conf
        -v
        -patmega328p
        -catmelice_isp
        -Pusb
        -Uflash:w:"C:/Program Files (x86)/.../optiboot_atmega328.hex":i
        -Ulock:w:0x0F:m
```

The output is the same as before, with the exception that the output in the Arduino IDE ends like this:

```sh
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0000
         0xff != 0x0f
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

and the output in the Windows terminal ends like this:

```sh
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: WARNING: invalid value for unused bits in fuse "lock", should be set to 1 according to datasheet
This behaviour is deprecated and will result in an error in future version
You probably want to use 0xcf instead of 0x0f (double check with your datasheet first).
avrdude: 1 bytes of lock verified

avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as FF
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as DE
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as FD
avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (E:FD, H:DE, L:FF)

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Here is the complete output:

```sh
avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : usb
         Using Programmer              : atmelice_isp
avrdude: usbhid_open(): No device found
avrdude: usbdev_open(): Found Atmel-ICE CMSIS-DAP, serno: J42700007942
avrdude: Found CMSIS-DAP compliant device, using EDBG protocol
         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : JTAG3_ISP
         Description     : Atmel-ICE (ARM/AVR) in ISP mode
         Vtarget         : 5.0 V
         SCK period      : 125.00 us

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f (probably m328p)
avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as FF
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as DE
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as FD
avrdude: NOTE: "flash" memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed
         To disable this feature, specify the -D option.
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: reading input file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr/bootloaders/optiboot/optiboot_atmega328.hex"
avrdude: writing flash (32768 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: 32768 bytes of flash written
avrdude: verifying flash memory against C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr/bootloaders/optiboot/optiboot_atmega328.hex:
avrdude: load data flash data from input file C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr/bootloaders/optiboot/optiboot_atmega328.hex:
avrdude: input file C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr/bootloaders/optiboot/optiboot_atmega328.hex contains 32768 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 32768 bytes of flash verified
avrdude: reading input file "0x0F"
avrdude: writing lock (1 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: 1 bytes of lock written
avrdude: verifying lock memory against 0x0F:
avrdude: load data lock data from input file 0x0F:
avrdude: input file 0x0F contains 1 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip lock data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: WARNING: invalid value for unused bits in fuse "lock", should be set to 1 according to datasheet
This behaviour is deprecated and will result in an error in future version
You probably want to use 0xcf instead of 0x0f (double check with your datasheet first).
avrdude: 1 bytes of lock verified

avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as FF
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as DE
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as FD
avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (E:FD, H:DE, L:FF)

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

### 2. Conclusions?

I don't know what to conclude from this. How is it possible that the same `avrdude` commands give a different results when they run in the Arduino IDE console compared to manually entering them in the Windows terminal?

One thing that comes to my mind is a timing issue. In the Arduino IDE, they run rapidly one after the other. When I enter them manually, there is considerably more time between them. However, that doesn't explain the difference in the output of the first command.

To test the timing-issue-theory, I put both commands in a `.bat` file. I ran the `.bat` file, and it worked. As both commands now run from the `.bat` file, there is almost no time in between them. This should mimic the behaviour of the Arduino IDE console very close.

### 3. Additional question

Well - it seems like it does work in the Windows console, and that's what ultimately matters to me (of course, it would be nice if it gets fixed in the Arduino IDE as well).

However, the following output scares me a little (it's at the end of the output for the second command):

```sh
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: WARNING: invalid value for unused bits in fuse "lock", should be set to 1 according to datasheet
This behaviour is deprecated and will result in an error in future version
You probably want to use 0xcf instead of 0x0f (double check with your datasheet first).
avrdude: 1 bytes of lock verified

avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as FF
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as DE
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as FD
avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (E:FD, H:DE, L:FF)

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Especially this phrase: `"This behaviour is deprecated and will result in an error in future version"`

I assume it has to do with the last flag in the second command: `-Ulock:w:0x0F:m`. Should I change that flag into: `-Ulock:w:0xCF:m`? The output suggests to look into the datasheet. However, I am not familiar with this chip, so I have no idea where to look in the datasheet.